# How to cut half lines into two columns?

Tags: vim, awk

I want to change the article ,cut half lines ,paste into two cloumns.

```
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus
line2 Sit odio placeat
line3 Consectetur quia
line4 Elit adipisicing
line5 Adipisicing modi
line6 Adipisicing quae
line7 Consectetur tempore
line8 Adipisicing elit
line9 Dolor nam
line10 Dolor esse
line11 Elit amet
line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

Trget:

```
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus     line7 Consectetur tempore
line2 Sit odio placeat                line8 Adipisicing elit 
line3 Consectetur quia                line9 Dolor nam 
line4 Elit adipisicing                line10 Dolor esse
line5 Adipisicing modi                line11 Elit amet 
line6 Adipisicing quae                line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

Please give a simple way with awk or vim.

[image]

My try with vim:

```
1.move cursor at the 7th line.
2.6dd
3.add many spaces at the end of each line
    %s/$/                         /
4.gg 
5.move cursor at the middle of the first line
6.ctrl+v
7.6g and down-side arrow
8.I
9.paste content in 0 regitor.
    ctrl+r+0
```

Failure,can't get what i want.
[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: update with my try in vim,failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this in Vim you can pad the first line with trailing spaces, then go to line 7th and enter this key sequence:

```
<c-v>05j$dgg$p
```

Explanation (`<c-v>` stands for `Ctrl-v`):

```
<c-v>05j$dgg$p
<c-v>                      " Enter visual-block mode
     0                     " Move to beginning of line
      5j                   " Move 5 lines below
        $                  " Move to last character of line
         d                 " Delete visual selection
          gg               " Move to first line
            $p             " Paste text at the end of the line
```

Alternativly enter this in Vim's command line (cursor should be on 7th line):

```
:exe "norm \<c-v>05j$dgg$p"
```

Comment: A little suggestion `exe "norm 7gg\<c-v>05j$dgg$p"` and `:%s/  \+/ /g`

Answer (score 8):

[`pr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) is the command you are looking for. Use it like this:

```
pr -t2 file.txt
```

`-t` omits the headers. `-2` means two columns.

Answer (score 3):

@hek2mgls pr solution is obviously the way to go but if you needed to to it with awk for some reason then that'd be:

```
$ awk '
    { a[NR]=$0; c=length($0); w=(c>w?c:w) }
    END { m=int((NR+1)/2); for (i=1;i<=m;i++) printf "%-*s\t%-s\n", w, a[i], a[m+i] }
' file
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus       line7 Consectetur tempore
line2 Sit odio placeat                  line8 Adipisicing elit
line3 Consectetur quia                  line9 Dolor nam
line4 Elit adipisicing                  line10 Dolor esse
line5 Adipisicing modi                  line11 Elit amet
line6 Adipisicing quae                  line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` and `paste`, for example:

```
split -l 6 file.txt parts
```

This will create 2 files each with 6 lines

Then you use `paste` to create a new file with the output of `split`:

```
paste parts* > file.txt
```

Based on your example it will produce something like this:

```
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus       line7 Consectetur tempore
line2 Sit odio placeat  line8 Adipisicing elit
line3 Consectetur quia  line9 Dolor nam
line4 Elit adipisicing  line10 Dolor esse
line5 Adipisicing modi  line11 Elit amet
line6 Adipisicing quae  line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

To make the space between lines even you could then use `expand` for example:

```
paste parts* | expand -t 20
```

And it will return:

```
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus       line7 Consectetur tempore
line2 Sit odio placeat                  line8 Adipisicing elit
line3 Consectetur quia                  line9 Dolor nam
line4 Elit adipisicing                  line10 Dolor esse
line5 Adipisicing modi                  line11 Elit amet
line6 Adipisicing quae                  line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

Now to use this from `vim` you could use:

```
:!split -l 6 % /tmp/parts; paste /tmp/parts* | expand -t 20 > %; rm /tmp/parts*
```

Comment: The first line is more longer than others ,make them equal width.

Answer (score 1):

... or use [`rs`( *— reshape a data array* )](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rs):

```
$ cat file | rs
line1 Ipsum dignissimos doloribus  line7 Consectetur tempore
line2 Sit odio placeat             line8 Adipisicing elit
line3 Consectetur quia             line9 Dolor nam
line4 Elit adipisicing             line10 Dolor esse
line5 Adipisicing modi             line11 Elit amet
line6 Adipisicing quae             line12 Amet quos recusandae
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare : add white spaces to make the first line to be longgest among range(1,6 lines).
In normal mode ,`7gg`

```
<c-v>6j$dgg$p
<c-v>                      " Enter visual-block mode
      6j                   " Move 5 lines below
        $                  " Move to last character of line
         d                 " Delete visual selection
          gg               " Move to first line
            $p             " Paste text at the end of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for sequence of output should be same as Input_file's sequence then following may help you on same.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file) '{val=FNR==((line/2)+1)||FNR==1?1:++val;a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v line=$(wc -l < Input_file) '
{
  val=FNR==((line/2)+1)||FNR==1?1:++val;
  a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $0:$0}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print a[i]}
}
'  Input_file
```

In case you want to make changes in Input_file itself then append following in above codes too `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`.

Comment: Take no effect .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, do you want to change Input_file itself? if yes then I will add a small piece of code too now, please confirm once.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, please check last line of my code too now and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: The first line is more longer than others ,make them equal width

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves changing the register from linewise to blockwise
and squeezing spaces.

```
fun! GiveItaNameYouWant()
    let @+=''
    7
    normal "+d}
    call setreg('+',@+,'b')
    normal gg
    execute "normal! A \<esc>"
    execute "normal! \"+p"
    %s/  \+/ /g
endfun
```

If you copy this function to the clipboard you can use it this way:

```
:@+ Enter
:call GiveItaNameYouWant() Enter
```

In my case I am removing extra spaces with the line `%s/  \+/ /g` if you do not want it just delete.